# Удаленная отладка в VS 2015 "падает" с .exe has triggered a breakpoint на Win2k8 Enterprise

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, отладка

При отладке любого кода, запущенного в `Windows 2008 R2 SP1`, с помощью удаленного отладчика `VS 2015`, получаю сообщение:

> application.exe has triggered a breakpoint

сразу после аттача. Стекфрейм для любого отлаживаемого приложения один и тот же -

> 0x00000000771d0530()

Продолжить или игнорить не получается - все время происходит останов с тем же сообщением.
Подобная проблема была в первой редакции `VS 2013`, и лечилась установкой отдельного обновления для `remote debugging tools`.
Сейчас попробовал все актуальные версии `rdb tools` - эффекта нет.

Еще раз повторю, наблюдается только на серверах с Windows 2008 R2 SP1.

При запуске отладки на локальном ПК проблем нет.
При отладке .net кода проблем тоже нет.

Comment: А в чем вопрос??? Переформулируйте, не понятно, что вы хотите и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Если бы вы сталкивались с таким - то поняли бы о чем речь. По теме вопроса гуглил много - у всех проблемы с кодом были. Мой случай нигде не встречается. Надеюсь на помощь сообщества.

Comment: Спасибо за наведение красоты, писал со смартфона